# Using sed to replace link into a html link

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Ok, I have a bunch of IPs in a file and I wish to use sed to append prefixes and suffixes.

For example, I have

```
http://profile/userA
1.2.3.4
http://profile/userB
2.2.3.4
http://profile/userC
3.2.3.4
http://profile/userD
4.2.3.4
```

How would I code it in bash such that sed would replace all IPs with something like

```
<a href="http://www.ip-tracker.org/locator/ip-lookup.php?ip=1.2.3.4">1.2.3.4</a>
<a href="http://www.ip-tracker.org/locator/ip-lookup.php?ip=2.2.3.4">2.2.3.4</a>
<a href="http://www.ip-tracker.org/locator/ip-lookup.php?ip=3.2.3.4">3.2.3.4</a>
<a href="http://www.ip-tracker.org/locator/ip-lookup.php?ip=4.2.3.4">4.2.3.4</a>
```

this?

Answer (score 2):

I would try something like this:

```
sed 's@.*@<a href="http://www.ip-tracker.org/locator/ip-lookup.php?ip=&">&</a>@' /tmp/ips
```

Comment: What if there were other values other than the numbers? example
randomtext1
1.1.1.1
randomtest
1.2.4.1

Comment: @Flare, the input for the original question was simply a list of ip numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option:

```
sed 's%^\([0-9.]*\)$%<a href="http://www.ip-tracker.org/locator/ip-lookup.php?ip=\1">\1</a>%'
```

Note that the regex `[0-9.]*` is used here to match the IP address in a concise way, but it assumes that you are already validating that the IP addresses are valid elsewhere.  The following page has a good example for a regex that will only match valid IP addresses, but you may need to adapt it to work with sed:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

`sed -e 's/^([0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3})/aaa\1
bbb/' InputFile`

Will prepend aaa and append bbb around your ip address.

Added after @sudo_O 's comment below, that this is not actually what was asked for.

Given the file :

```
1.2.3.4
2.2.3.4
3.2.3.4
4.2.3.4
192.168.0.54
1192.168.0.54
 Opps some text 192.168.0.54 on this line.
```

Then

`sed -e 's@[\s]*([0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3})@\1@' InputFile`

Gives you,

```
<a href="http://www.ip-tracker.org/locator/ip-lookup.php?ip=1.2.3.4">1.2.3.4</a>
<a href="http://www.ip-tracker.org/locator/ip-lookup.php?ip=2.2.3.4">2.2.3.4</a>
<a href="http://www.ip-tracker.org/locator/ip-lookup.php?ip=3.2.3.4">3.2.3.4</a>
<a href="http://www.ip-tracker.org/locator/ip-lookup.php?ip=4.2.3.4">4.2.3.4</a>
<a href="http://www.ip-tracker.org/locator/ip-lookup.php?ip=192.168.0.54">192.168.0.54</a>
1<a href="http://www.ip-tracker.org/locator/ip-lookup.php?ip=192.168.0.54">192.168.0.54</a>
 Opps some text <a href="http://www.ip-tracker.org/locator/ip-lookup.php?ip=192.168.0.54">192.168.0.54</a> on this line.
```

I didn't give you the 2nd solution initially, because I tried and make the regex easier to understand, but since getting the comment I thought I should try again.

Note the invalid IP does not get converted, also there is no assumption that the IP's are alone on a line

Comment: You are using `ERE` without explicitly turning it on or escaping, this will fail and beside it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Ok, I'll append a more better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
awk 'NR%2==0 {
    print "<a href=\"http://www.ip-tracker.org/locator/ip-lookup.php?ip="$1"\">"$1"</a>"
}' file
```